# bash if then cp as hardlinks

Tags: bash, find, sh, hardlink

I would like for the following to hardlink all files to destination, except those directories defined. The find piece is working, but it won't copy any files.

```
#!/bin/sh
tag_select=$1
source=$3
dest="/backup/"

{
if [[ "$1" = "backup" ]]; then
    find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ! -name "dir1" ! -name "dir2" | while read line
    do
        cp -lr "$3" "$dest"
    done
fi
}
```

Please note, I do not want to use rysnc as I would like to create hardlinks in the destination. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What you wrote does not really make sense: you while loop continuously creates the same hard link. What do you want to do, exactly? What are these `dir1`, `dir2`, `source`...?

Comment: Sorry for the mess. To fill everyone in a little more of what I'm trying to do. I'm running rtorrent which I would like to run the hardlink.sh script above. Currently the script works well simply cp -lr everything. I'm looking to exclude unnecessary dirs so when I download, I don't waste time with those directories that I don't need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you know why `"$2"` doesn't appear anywhere, so we will just presume you are correct. You also understand that every file you find `source` (e.g. `"$3"`) will be linked to `$dest` no matter what filenames are discovered by `find` because you make no use of `"$line"` that you use as your `while read line` loop variable. It appears from the question, you want to link all files in `source` in `dest` (you must confirm this is your intent) If so, `find` itself is all you need, e.g.

```
find source -maxdepth 1 ! -name "dir1" ! -name "dir2" -execdir cp -lr '{}' "$dest" \;
```

which will find all files (and directories) for 1-level and hardlink each of the files in dest. If that wasn't your intent, please let me know and I'm happy to help further. Your original posts was somewhat an opaque pot of shell stew...

Comment: This doesn't full fill what I'm asking. I need the script to run in a if then because the contents requested to be copied need to be tagged as "backup".

Comment: Apologies, hasty response. This will work, but as I mentioned below to tripleee and Mr.A, if the source files are in a directory, how can I copy that dir as a whole, not the individual files into dest?

Comment: You limit your `find` search with the `-type d` option --or-- you write a short helper script called by `-exec script '{}'` where the first argument is the filename (or directory name) from `find` and in the script you test `if [ -d "$1" ]; then #do something with dir; else #do something with file; fi`

Comment: Thank you, -type d works, but it breaks if it's a single file under no directory. We'll need to do the second option, but can you please spoon feed it to me? I don't understand how to create the necessary initial directory. My thoughts, wouldn't mkdir -p won't it create the full path under dest?

Comment: That's where the helper script comes in. You can specify either `-type d` or `-type f` with find to limit what `find` collects to one or the other. However, to have `find` return all and then handle files or directories in separate ways, you need to write a small (helper) script that takes a single argument (the filename) and then tests whether it is a file or directory and takes the appropriate action. Just make sure the script is executable and then `find source -maxdepth 1 ! -name "dir1" ! -name "dir2" -exec ./scriptname '{}' \;`  (note `-exec` instead of `-execdir`)

Comment: I'm really trying here...This is helper script, I can't get the folder nested correctly, it duplicates the full path. Really appreciate your help.

if [ -d $1 ]; then
    cp -lr $1 "$dest"
else
    if [ -f $2 ]; then
#    cp -l $2 "$dest"
    fi
fi

Comment: You are getting close. You can only pass **ONE** variable to the help script, it will either be the name of a file, or the name of a directory. So it will all be `"$1"` ("$2" has no dog in this fight). Just pass whatever `find` sends you. `if [ -d "$1" ]; then cp -lr "$1" "$dest"; else cp -l "$i" "$dest"; fi` Of course make sure `"$dest"` is where both need to go. You can trim components with `basename` or `dirname` as needed.

Answer (score 0):

try This

```
#!/bin/sh
tag_select=$1;
source=$2;
dest="/backup/";
if [ "$1" = "backup" ]; then
  find $source -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ! -name "dir1" ! -name "dir2" -exec cp -lr {} "$dest" \;
fi
```

your command should be

```
./code.sh backup source_folder_path
```

example

```
./code.sh backup ~/Desktop
```

Try below code for only files in the dir

```
find $source -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec sh -c "ln -f \"\$(realpath {})\" \"$dest\$(basename {})\"" \;
```

you cant hard link folders.

Comment: This is some what working. The contents of source directory (lets say 100 files) are being copied straight into destination /backup/. How can I ensure the files are kept in a source directory? For example, instead of /backup/file1..., it will copy as /backup/Ubuntu/file1...etc.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `find` command with a simple glob; this also has the benefit of working for *any* valid file name, not just the ones that don't have newlines in them.

```
#!/bin/sh
tag_select=$1
source=$3
dest="/backup/"

if [ "$1" = "backup" ]; then
    for f in "$source"/*; do
        case $f in
            dir1|dir2) continue ;;
        esac
        cp -lr "$f" "$dest"
    done
fi
```

Comment: This isn't working at all, still copies all directories.